# PySpark best way to filter df based on columns from different df's

Tags: pyspark

I have a DF `A_DF` which has among others two columns say `COND_B` and `COND_C`. Then I have 2 different df's `B_DF` with `COND_B` column and `C_DF` with `COND_C` column.

Now I would like to filter `A_DF` where the value match in one **OR** the other. Something like:

```
df = A_DF.filter((A_DF.COND_B == B_DF.COND_B) | (A_DF.COND_C == C_DF.COND_C))
```

But I found out it is not possible like this.

*EDIT*
error: `Attribute CON_B#264,COND_C#6 is missing from the schema: [... COND_B#532, COND_C#541 ]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: COND_B,COND_C. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;` looks like I can filter only on same DF because of the #number added on the fly..

So I first tried to do a list from `B_DF` and `C_DF` and use filter based on that but it was too expensive to use `collect()` on 100m of records.

So I tried:

```
AB_DF = A_DF.join(B_DF, 'COND_B', 'left_semi')
AC_DF = A_DF.join(C_DF, 'COND_C', 'left_semi')

df = AB_DF.unionAll(AC_DF).dropDuplicates()
```

`dropDuplicates()` I used to removed duplicate records where both conditions where true. But even with that I got some unexpected results.

Is there some other - smoother solution to do it simply? Something like an `EXISTS` statement in SQL?

*EDIT2*
I tried SQL based on @mck response:

```
e.createOrReplaceTempView('E')
b.createOrReplaceTempView('B')
p.createOrReplaceTempView('P')

df = spark.sql("""select * from E where exists (select 1 from B where E.BUSIPKEY = B.BUSIPKEY) or exists (select 1 from P where E.PCKEY = P.PCKEY)""")

my_output.write_dataframe(df)
```

with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myproject/abc.py", line 45, in my_compute_function
    df = spark.sql("""select * from E where exists (select 1 from B where E.BUSIPKEY = B.BUSIPKEY) or exists (select 1 from P where E.PCKEY = P.PCKEY)""")
TypeError: sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sqlQuery'
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the error popping-out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of using `exists` should work. You can do:

```
A_DF.createOrReplaceTempView('A')
B_DF.createOrReplaceTempView('B')
C_DF.createOrReplaceTempView('C')

df = spark.sql("""
    select * from A 
    where exists (select 1 from B where A.COND_B = B.COND_B) 
    or exists (select 1 from C where A.COND_C = C.COND_C)
""")
```

Comment: I have never used the sql query in pyspark. But I tried now with error: `
TypeError: sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sqlQuery'` It looks like to me in `sql()` are 2 arguments required, aren't?

Comment: It seems like you're not passing the query correctly to spark.sql(). Could you show the code you used by editing your question?

Comment: I did, please check above

Comment: how was your `spark` defined?

Comment: was it defined like in https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession ?

Comment: I just imported `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession as spark`

Comment: that's not the right way. Please follow https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession to create a spark session properly.

Comment: you know, I am using Foundry platform to make this transformations. There I don't take care about the sessions as it starts automatically on background. But from their docs: The underlying SparkSession is available in all Python transforms as the spark variable. You can use this variable to create new dataframes..

Comment: Ah, then you shouldn't do the import

Comment: Is there a way in PySpark (not SQL) to achieve the same result?

Comment: I'm afraid not... please try again with a new notebook/session and remember not to import the spark session, and just use the default spark variable

Comment: That's what I thought, but then the spark is undefined..:/

Comment: the hint on hover `spark.sql` sais `sql(self, sqlQuery)`

Comment: If it's undefined, then could you create the spark variable following https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession ?

Comment: Also I wonder how you created the dataframes, if you don't have a spark variable??

Comment: I have tranformation with inputs and output, then my transpormation function where I take those inputs do the logig and write to the output. Something like: `from transforms.api import transform, incremental, Input, Output, configure @transform(
my_output=Output("/PATH"),e=Input("/PATH")
def my_compute_function(e, my_output):
    e = e.dataframe()
   # the logic here
    my_output.write_dataframe(e.join(filtered_b, condition, "leftsemi"))` Anyway I tried to start the session based on the link you sent and its running now, so fingers crossed! Will let you know once completed.